# Are we the only species to name our planet after what it's made of?

Tags: star-trek

I know our planet isn't entirely composed of earth, but a lot of it is.

In the *Star Trek* canon, do we ever encounter any species that names their planet after it's primary composite material, and not after the people who live there or some culturally significant figure?

Comment: How do you know it's not the other way around?

Comment: I don't think we *did* name our planet after its material, I think "earth" meant "the ground," and so we just naturally referred to "the earth" in opposition to "the sky," and then later in opposition to "space."  It just naturally became the name for our planet, the same way "the Moon" wasn't so much named as described: it's a moon, it's our moon, so it's the Moon.  We're living on the ground, we're living on the earth, so we're living on the Earth.

Comment: Hard to say. We don't generally know the names of alien planets in the aliens' native languages, or know when the name we know is such a name. Qo'noS may be the only unambiguous case.

Comment: How do you know that the Vulcan word for dirt isn't "Vulcan"?

Comment: @Nerrolken that's actually a very valid point, well said.

Comment: Ground? Dirt? Soil? Mud? Which one was it again? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be difficult to pinpoint a negative here. Most of the planet names are proper nouns, so the translator wouldn't translate them. When an alien is talking about the ground on their planet, the translator would translate it to the listener's native language (in our case, English).

So from our perspective, the aliens always *seem* to use two separate words, but there's no way to verify that. For all we know 95% of the races in the show use the same word to represent both concepts.

Further complicating issues, most of the cultures we see in the show span multiple planets and/or star systems. If the culture started on Barabos and now they've colonized seven other star systems, they might all refer to the ground as "barabos" centuries after they no longer refer to the origin planet as Barabos. Without inventing both language and its history for every single culture, it would be impossible to know how often this occurs.

The etymology of *[earth](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=earth)* shows that we didn't use the name *Earth* for our planet until long after we used the word for dirt. However, I'm not sure that means the planet was named after the stuff it's composed of. In essence, *the Earth* is also *the earth*, so the term rightly applies to both equally. Sure, you could be pedantic and find some definition where the two diverge, but in common experience they were the same when the proper noun was forming.

So we could think of *earth* as applying to part of the planet, while *Earth* refers to all the earth there is. Technically, we could say that implies the ground on other planets isn't made of earth, but I think we again need to look at when the word was formed.

We didn't name our planet after its composition. We simply turned the common word that logically already referred to the planet into a proper noun.

To my knowledge, there's no definite, canon correlation between a planet's name and the word used to describe something said planet is made of, but that's not remotely proof that Earth is unique in this way within Star Trek canon.

Comment: "Earth" comes from the Indo-European root "to plow", as does "arable".  The Indo-European root *ters (dry, arid, thirst) gave rise to the Latin "terra" (land, earth) "presumably dry land as opposed to the sea".  Mario Pei, "The Families of Words".